# what is the maximum background running time of app in android?

Tags: android

I am new in Android development. My app need to work in background process.
Please reply me that what will be maximum background running time for app?. 
if I put app in background.

Comment: No limit or No Maximum Time ........ Depend upon your Background Service and Device Capability.... its not valid questions.......

Comment: `maximum background running time` means time interval or no. of processes ?

Comment: It is a valid question. because in iPhone it is 600 seconds.
My question is if I put app in background, will it run or process in background and how long will it work in background?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to run long-running background tasks, you should consider implementing a [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).